# get center word and sentences in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to the bootstrap. I have following bootstrap code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="padding-top: 25px; ">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="background-color: #F0F8FF;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/car.png')}}" alt="profile Pic" height="50" width="50">Car
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need the first image and then under the image 'car' word in the center to the div and under word some discription about the car. like image of this. how can I do this?

See image here:

[image: see image here]

Comment: no any idea here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've provided I assume you are using Bootstrap 3.x and so the below code reflects that.  The two main classes you *might* rely on here (because there are multiple methods to achieve your desired outcome) would be `.text-center` and `.center-block`.  The first simply applies `text-align: center` to the element while the latter alters the display and left/right margin to force centering.

```css
.your-custom-background {
  background: #F0F8FF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="your-custom-background text-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50/50/" alt="profile Pic" height="50" width="50" class="center-block">
        <p>Car</p>
        <p>Some additional description goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A couple of additional notes as you mention you are new to Bootstrap:

(1) Because Bootstrap's Grid applies padding to the column wrapper, you should avoid applying backgrounds directly to this element unless your desire is to re-color both the content area AND the gutter.

(2) It's not clear why you're using `.col-md-3` inside your `.col-md-10` but columns must *always* be wrapped within a `.row`, even when nested.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <img class="d-block m-auto" src="https://placehold.it/50x50"/>
    <div>Car</div>
    <div>62.3333</div>
    <div>text text text texttext texttext texttext text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working but little bit problem here image did not center properly. do you have some idea about this....